# Angular click event updates variable but not javascript onclick method

Tags: javascript, angular, onclick, click

I have the following setup:

**app.component.ts**

```
prop:string = 'foo';

test(val){
 this.prop = val;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
{{prop}}

<button (click)="test('bar')">Test</button>
<a href="#" onclick="test('bar'); return false;">Test2</a>
```

Both call test() successfully, and the 'prop' variable changes to 'bar'. My question is why only the first (click) event updates the view whereas the second does not? I've also tried using a timeout and the ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges() method inside of test().

Comment: Angular is a thing that lives in its own realm. That realm is a separate and distinct world that works within the DOM. But, since it is separate, the DOM events like `onclick` are not recognized within the Angular realm. Since the `onclick` handler executes in the DOM and Angular's output exists in the DOM, the change is made without Angular's knowledge. Since Angular doesn't know about it, Angular cannot change internally to reflect the click event. So, one must tell the event to work inside the realm of Angular. That is done through binding the event to Angular's realm.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax difference between both hence *event triggering* which causes **`detectChanges`** by default angular DOM manipulation.

> () is one-way event binding, which passes data from view to
> component.

So in your case, `button` is triggering an event which causes *detectChanges* where as not with `<a>` tag.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I mean to say that there is an event  triggering which causes the `detectChanges` which is not happening with `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` scope is the DOM element it is attached to it. So clicking that you should get an error as there is no such thing in your `<a>` tag as `test()` function. You can see the scope yourself:

```
<a href="#" onclick="console.log(this)">Test2</a>
```

Use an event listener instead - `<a href="#"(click)="test('bar')">Test2</a>`